# C# Adding Multiple Elements to a IList in one line - AddRange not available

Tags: c#

I want to shorten the code and add multiple items to list at once, I get error.

> "No overload method Add taking 2 arguments"

The list has some items added and i want to add new ones

**IList**

```
public IList<SelectListItem> Cmsentities { get; set; }
```

**method**

```
Cmsentities.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "publish",
                Text = "nur veröffentlichte"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "nopublish",
                Text = "nur nicht veröffentlichte"
            });
```

Comment: You can use `var Cmsentities = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{}, new SelectListItem{} };`

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually this way previously added item of list will be deleted. I want to keep those and still add more.

Comment: Use `AddRange()`. Example: `Cmsentities.Add(new[] { new SelectListItem(), new SelectListItem() });`

Comment: You can create an extension method `Add(params SelectListItem[] items)` and use it.

Comment: This question is in no way _about_ [tag:asp.net-core]. Do not add tags to your question except those that indicate what the question is _about_.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SelvaS's comment, you can also use List.AddRange(IEnumerable) Method if Cmsentities is already instantiated.

it'd look like

```
Cmsentities.AddRange(new List<SelectListItem> {new SelectListItem(), new SelectListItem()})
```

Comment: `new SelectListItem[]` can perhaps also be used and avoid the creation of an instance of a generic class.

Comment: @Olivier Or just `new[]`.

Comment: Since what C# language version ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Implicitly-typed arrays were introduced in C# 3.0